Problema con la Instrucción BL (brach with link) en ARM CortexM0+
Estoy incursionando en el desarrollo baremetal de microcontroladores ARM CortexM. En particular estoy trabajando con chip de arquitectura ARM de 32bits con un CortexM0+.
El problema que me surgió luego de compilar el proyecto y cargarlo en la placa. Es que al llegar a la función main() dentro del reset_handler, la placa detecta un default_handler. Luego de depurar y ver documentación oficial. Me dí cuenta que la arquitectura con CortexM0+ no usa la instrucción en assembler BL(branch with link).
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0662/b/The-Cortex-M0--Instruction-Set/Branch-and-control-instructions/B--BL--BX--and-BLX?lang=en
El programa lo he hecho en C y no sé que hacer si quiero seguir codificando en C y no pasar a Assember.
Las flags que estoy usando para la compilación y linkado son las siguientes:
FLAGS_C=    -c 
-Wall 
-mcpu=cortex-m0plus 
-mthumb 
-ggdb3 
-std=gnu11 
-ffreestanding 
-ffunction-sections 
-fdata-sections 
--specs=nano.specs 
-mfloat-abi=soft 
-mlittle-endian 
-march=armv6-m
FLAGS_LD=   -nostartfiles 
-mcpu=cortex-m0plus 
-mthumb 
--specs=nano.specs 
-mfloat-abi=soft 
-mlittle-endian 
-march=armv6-m 
-T $(STARTUP_DIR)/flash.ld 
-Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROJECT).map 
-Wl,--gc-sections
y las estoy compilando con arm-none-eabi-gcc
Agradezco su ayuda ya que llevo demasiados días sin poder continuar con mi aprendizaje.
También agradezco si conocen comunidades en español que traten temas de informática, y electrónica :)
